# Launch Intent on click of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, button, android-intent, expandablelistview

Good evening everyone !

I am currently working on an ExpandableListView.
The parent contains 1 ImageView.
The child contains 1 TextView and 3 Buttons.
In terms of display, no problem: everything works as I want.

However, I want to add actions to my buttons and I realize that when I put a SetOnclickListener in the getChildView I am not able to launch a new INTENT.

The examples I find on the internet seem to show only clicks on dynamic elements. However, the buttons are not dynamic in my case.
I planned to use a variable to do a SWITCH and thus launch the right INTENT.
But since it doesn't work, I wonder if my direction is the right one.

MaintActivity.java

```
package com.evo.tab2escape;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class jeux2 extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;

List<Integer> headerData;
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<ChildDataModel>> childData;
ChildDataModel childDataModel;
Context mContext;
ArrayList<ChildDataModel> logo0,logo1,logo2,logo3,logo4,logo5,logo6,logo7,logo8,logo9,logo10,logo11;
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jeux2);

    mContext = this;
    headerData = new ArrayList<>();
    childData = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ChildDataModel>>();
    logo0 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo1 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo2 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo3 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo4 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo5 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo6 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo7 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo8 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo9 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo10 = new ArrayList<>();
    logo11 = new ArrayList<>();

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpandableListView);

    // populate data
    //      Adding header data
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo0);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo1);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo2);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo3);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo4);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo5);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo6);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo7);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo8);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo9);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo10);
    headerData.add(R.drawable.logo11);

    //      Adding child data
    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test0","logo0");
    logo0.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(0),logo0);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test1","logo1");
    logo1.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(1),logo1);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test2","logo2");
    logo2.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(2),logo2);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test3","logo3");
    logo3.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(3),logo3);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test4","logo4");
    logo4.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(4),logo4);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test5","logo5");
    logo5.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(5),logo5);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test6","logo6");
    logo6.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(6),logo6);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test7","logo7");
    logo7.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(7),logo7);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Test8","logo8");
    logo8.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(8),logo8);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"test09","logo9");
    logo9.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(9),logo9);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"test10","logo10");
    logo10.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(10),logo10);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"test11","logo11");
    logo11.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(11),logo11);


    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, headerData, childData);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



    //--------------------------child click listener--------------------------
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {
            Log.d("TEST", "onChildClick: " + groupPosition + " " + childPosition + " " + id + " " + parent);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "heeeeeeeeerrrrreeeee!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    //group expanded
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int headPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && headPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                expListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = headPosition;
        }
    });

    //group collapsed
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int headPosition) {
        }
    });




    //--------------------------RETOUR--------------------------
    Button retour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retour);
    retour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent Intent_next = new Intent(jeux2.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(Intent_next);
        }

    });

    //--------------------------HISTO--------------------------
    TextView histo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.histo);
    histo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent Intent_next = new Intent(jeux2.this, historique.class);
            startActivity(Intent_next);
        }

    });





}
}


class ChildDataModel
{

long id;
String txt;
String aventure;


public ChildDataModel(int id, String explications, String aventure) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setTxt(explications);

}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTxt() {
    return txt;
}

public void setTxt(String explications) {
    this.txt = explications;
}

public String getTxt_aventure() {
    return aventure;
}


@Override
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString();
}
}
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
package com.evo.tab2escape;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<Integer> headerData; // Images

// child data in format of header , child
private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ChildDataModel>> childData;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ChildDataModel>> childData) {
    this._context = context;
    this.headerData = listDataHeader;
    this.childData = childData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this.childData.get(this.headerData.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ChildDataModel child = (ChildDataModel) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView explications = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.explications);
    explications.setText(child.getTxt());

    Button play = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.play);
    Button doc = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doc);
    Button param = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.param);

    final String aventure = child.getTxt_aventure();

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "poulet: ");
        }
    });

    doc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "poulet: ");
        }
    });

    param.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "poulet: ");
        }
    });





    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.childData.get(this.headerData.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.headerData.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.headerData.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    ImageView logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    int imageId = this.headerData.get(groupPosition);
    logo.setImageResource(imageId);


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

list_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp">
</Space>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/divers">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/explications"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Jouer"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bouton_main"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </Button>
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </Space>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/doc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Documents"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bouton_main"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </Button>
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </Space>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/param"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Paramètres"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bouton_main"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </Button>
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </Space>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can somoene help me ?
I want to start a new intent on click on Button.

Edit : i add child Click Listener on MainActivity but its works only if i set clickable,focusable = false on the 3 Buttons in layout list_item.xml.
And than the click is on the complete child. I can't say if the click is on Button 1, 2 or 3.
Can we fix it ?

Comment: this answer will be userful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61270513/12386821

Comment: Thanks, but i don't get it.
I add expListView.setOnChildClickListener in MainActivity but its never use or call.

Comment: Plz see my Edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I do this in ExpandableListAdapter in getChildView.

```
        param.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent next = new Intent(parent.getContext(), parametres.class);
            parent.getContext().startActivity(next);
        }
    });
```